# for loop causes random segfault C++

Tags: c++, loops, segmentation-fault

My program runs fine until I try to add a simple for loop and then I get a seg fault. I'll go ahead and post the main so you can see:

```
     using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){                                                              
struct question questions[argc-1];                                                             //Array of questions to be filled by loop.
int sizeOfQuestions = argc-1;                                                                    //number of questions passed in at run time
int numLines = 0;                                                                            //number of lines in file
for(int i=1;i<argc;i++){                                                                         //Test loop to make sure the command line file names are read in
    std::cout << argv[i] << " says hello" << std::endl;
}

for(int count=0;count<sizeOfQuestions;count++){                                              //This loop places the information from the files into structs
    char* fileName;
    std::string word = argv[count+1];
    word+=".txt";
    strcpy(fileName, word.c_str());
    std::fstream questionFile (fileName, std::fstream::in);                                 //Open the file
    if(questionFile.good()){
        cout << "In File:  \t" << fileName << endl;
        setQuestionFileName(&(questions[count]),word);                                          
        getline(questionFile,questions[count].programNum);
        getline(questionFile,questions[count].programDesc);
        getline(questionFile,questions[count].programPoints);
        getline(questionFile,questions[count].programInput);
        questionFile.close();
    }else{
        cout << "Could not open file!!!" << endl;
    }

}

sort(questions,questions+sizeOfQuestions);

display(questions[0]);
cout << "" << endl;
cout << "" << endl;
display(questions[1]);


return 0;

}
```

Will display exactly what it should. But when I change the last section of code from

```
    display(questions[0]);
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    display(questions[1]);
```

To:

```
     for(int k=0;k<2;k++){
     display(questions[k]);
     cout << "" << endl;
     cout << "" << endl;
     }
```

I get a segmentation fault right after the very first for loop where is says `"says hello"`, why is that? Even if I remove the display() and just do a couple cout statements in the loop, it still breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have these lines

```
char* fileName;
...
strcpy(fileName, word.c_str());
```

But nowhere do you *allocate* memory for `fileName`.

Because uninitialized local variables (like `fileName`) have indeterminate values, using them without initialization (like allocating memory for a pointer) leads to *undefined behavior*.

In this case, you don't actually *need* the `fileName` pointer. In C++11 the file streams constructors have been changed to accept `std::string` (see e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream)), and if you have an older library then just use `word.c_str()` when opening the file.

So instead skip the `fileName` variable, and just do

```
std::ifstream questionFile (word);
```

or possibly

```
std::ifstream questionFile (word.c_str());
```

Comment: Is that what causes it? That simple?

Comment: @user2990286 Yes, it's "that simple" :)

Comment: Changed a few things and I'm working, thanks to this. Appreciate it!

Comment: If I could give you a thousand green checkmarks I would, your edit works even better than the fix I had done!